# How do I add a link to a checkbox label in a struts2 form

Tags: forms, struts2

I'm trying to add a link to a label in a struts2 form with the xhtml theme.  Is there a way I can do it using a struts tag or do I have to use CSS to position a normal link?

Answer (score 0):

Just change the theme to simple and use regular html. I started off trying to use the xhtml theme, I really gave it a run but it just wasn't intuitive for me.  So I just changed the layout to simple everywhere.

In struts.xml just add

```
 <constant name="struts.ui.theme" value="simple" />
```

(right after the struts tag)

If you are working in an existing application, you can set the theme on a per page basis, you'll find all this on the struts2 site. http://struts.apache.org/2.0.14/docs/can-i-change-theme-on-a-per-page-basis.html